# Using zmq_conect a port befor zmq_bind, return suncces

Tags: zeromq

I`m using zero mq 3.2.0 C++ libary. I use zmq_connect to connect a port before zmq_bild. But this function return success. How can I know connect fail? My code is:

```
void *ctx = zmq_ctx_new(1);
void *skt = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_SUB);
int ret = zmq_connect(skt, "tcp://192.168.9.97:5561"); // 192.168.9.97:5561 is not binded
// zmq_connect return zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a feature of zeromq, connection status and so on is abstracted away from you. There is no exposed information you can check to see if you're connected or not AFAIK. This means that you can connect even if the server is temporarily down, and zeromq will handle everything when the server comes available later. This can be both a blessing and a curse.

What most people end up doing if they need to know connection status is to implement some sort of heartbeat. REQ/REP ping/pong for example.

Have a look at the [lazy pirate pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Client-side-Reliability-Lazy-Pirate-Pattern) for an example of how to ensure reliability from a client perspective.